# Are Undergraduates allowed to collaborate with other students for their dissertation research?

Tags: research-process, undergraduate, collaboration

I'm not sure if this is common practice or not, but much like how we see co-authorship in research papers, I was wondering if an undergrad would be allowed to collaborate with other students (possibly from other institutions) for their research project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes !**

Undergraduates are definitely allowed to collaborate with other students (undergraduate/graduate) for their senior thesis/research project/dissertation etc.

Of course, the degree to which they can successfully collaborate depends on many things including their faculty adviser.

For instance, as an undergraduate I collaborated with students from Civil Engineering/Construction Management and used some of the results we obtained in my undergraduate thesis.

Currently, I am a doctoral candidate and I have worked with undergraduates in the past whose thesis has sprouted from the results of our active collaboration in a project.

Comment: Could someone please explain the downvote on this answer please?